# PHP web application loading issue - Subdomain vs Subfolder for loading

Tags: php, jquery, subdomain, loading

This web application is a PHP internal project is a Booking System can login 10 Admin staffs only. I used *Homer Responsive Template* (PHP, MySQLi, jQuery, Ajax, HTML5, CSS3)

Accessing the domain currently like below:

http://www.example.com           :  static 4 page website

http://www.example.com/liveapp/  :  internal web application with heavy data

http://demo.example.com          :  demo for the above application

**Problem Facing**

- Loading issue.
- Navigation through pages are too long.

**Tried**

Im trying different options to solve the loading issue. I optimized queries, loops, javascripts, changed default full load jquery pagination to PHP pagination with 15 rows/page. still the page load take too much time and navigation to pages also takes time.

**Question**

- Based on the circumstances explained above what else I can try to solve the loading issue?
- Thinking of subfolder to subdomain. Which is faster to load subdomain or subfolder for a heavily loaded data?

**Stackoverflow**

I have searched and found regarding `seo`, `url rewrite` and `search engines`. But Im seeking advice for Performance of subdomain over subfolder and loading issues facing.

Comment: this issue is in your local machine or in server?

Comment: @Vigneshwaran issue in server

Comment: other application which you said are faster, are they too in the same server deployed?

Comment: yes. just static websites

Comment: you can find which request takes time to load more using debugger. Right click the webpage and choose "Inspect Element" then click the tab "Network", now load fresh the page without closing the debugger tray. you can see the list of web request to server and the time taken to respond.

Comment: I think it may be a blocking javascript. let's see https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS

Comment: There are many obvious reasons to slow down your website. Check the render blocking scripts or css, not optimized images, Page size, or maybe your slow webserver. Please audit your site in google pagespeed

Comment: @ Vigneshwaran; Panupong; Saad Suri;  thanks ill check on these

Comment: @SaadSuri How to audit in google pagespeed? Also this is an login application

Comment: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/ Enter your website link find the error and solve it or go to https://gtmetrix.com

Comment: @SaadSuri I usually use gtmetrix.com for non-login applications. How to check for a page accesable after login using these